# No ACK on address with bme280

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

Recently bought [gy bme280](http://www.dx.com/p/gy-bme280-3-3-high-precision-barometric-pressure-module-purple-436672?utm_rid=37321690&utm_source=admitad&utm_medium=affiliate&admitad_uid=a214607b94301d8d69d148c3a17e2c0c#.WxXSAFMvwnU) and trying to connect it with the Esp8266 Nodemcu V3 Esp 12.

Followed the instructions [here](https://www.embeddedadventures.com/datasheets/BME280.pdf) for the hookup and then for the code, followed [this](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/bme280/) tutorial.

I built the firmware from https://nodemcu-build.com/ a couple of days ago from master.

The debug logs shows this

```
Queue empty
Running
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614844, func:0
Function platform_gpio_mode() is called. pin_mux:1610614848, func:0
i2c setup result --> 100000
mode: b7
humidity oss: 5
config: f0
No ACK on address: 76
No ACK on address: 77
bme280 setup result --> 
nil
pm open,type:2 0
```

My code

```
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
scl = 1
sda = 2
i2cResult = i2c.setup(0, sda, scl, i2c.SLOW) -- call i2c.setup() only once
print("i2c setup result --> " .. i2cResult)
local bmeResult = bme280.setup()
print("bme280 setup result --> ")
print(bmeResult)
```

The connections between BME280 and ESP8266 I have are

SDO -> G

CSB -> 3V

SDA -> D2

SCL -> D1

VCC -> 3V

GND -> G

Any idea of what is failing or what else can I do to troubleshoot it?

Comment: A hint maybe: https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/issues/1994#issuecomment-306283212

Comment: looking at the code in master (i2c.c), I do not understand what does the i2c.setup() returning 100000 mean.

Comment: As per https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/i2c/#i2csetup it's "the selected speed". It's the constant `i2c.SLOW` you pass to `setup` defined at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/modules/i2c.c#L151. It references https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/platform/platform.h#L237

Comment: thanks @MarcelStör . Regarding the issue mentioned my problem is before even reading as "bme280.setup()" returning nil. Might be some error with the hookup but no clue for the moment. Will change the connectors as a last try.